# How can I optimize size of App.js Vue.js application as its size is huge

Tags: javascript, vue.js, optimization

I have developed my Vuejs app within Laravel and now I see its dev version is 7 MB, I know production will reduce its size a lot but still I am looking for some suggestions to reduce size. I noticed now that as I am using few components from bootstrap-vue which is significantly increasing size. I cant remove them as it is being used everywhere like loader and other stuff. How can we just import the least of them ? I have applied few other ways of lazy loading components. Just looking for solution of bootstrap-vue.

Thanks

[Better View of analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLXe7.png)

[Webpack Analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVBG7.png)

[Compiled Assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A31G5.png)

Comment: You want to use a **JS bundle inspector** - similar to one of the those hard drive inspection tools that help you find where your disk is being used, they show a visualisation of the bundle and which npm modules are taking the most space. 

These depend on the build tool you're using.

If you're using eg webpack, google 'webpack JS bundle inspector'.

Comment: Actually I know about that but at the moment, bootstrap-vue needs to be fixed as i am using few of its components and its taking almost 4 MB

Comment: Excellent - can you you add the output of the bundle inspector into the question? Once you know what's taking up the room, you can switch to relative imports (eg rather than import bootstrap vue, `import { something, someThingElse } from "bootstrap-vue"`) or replace / remove modules accordingly.  But that's *if* bootstrap vue is the module using all the space.

Comment: I am using **import { something, someThingElse } from "bootstrap-vue"** already but still its taking a lot, as I am importing 7 components

Comment: Are you sure you're using the production build of `bootstrap-vue`?

Comment: I’d still add the bundle analyser to the question- without seeing it we don’t know that it’s necessarily bootstrap vue taking up the space.

Comment: mikemaccana, can you check now ? I have added the report in my question

Comment: @Saad Is that report based on a production build?

Comment: Hiws, no its dev build, actually I mentioned in the question that the production would be a lot smaller but I still need some thing to make it at least 4 MB in dev build total.

Comment: You should never analyse a dev build, it makes little sense and proper treeshaking won't take place. So you don't get a good picture of how it will actually be.

Comment: Hiws, I understand that but issue is that it is taking lot of space and will take in production as well, so I want to reduce the size and as I mentioned it is bootstrap vue that is taking  most of it

Comment: Hey guys ? what you think ?

Comment: No clues so far ? I am looking forward to your answers ?